# VS Code not able to recognize SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, flask, visual-studio-code, import, sqlalchemy

I have installed SQLAlchemy through the command line by:

```
pip install SQLAlchemy
```

and have also done:

```
pip install Flask-SQLAlchemy
```

I am trying to run these lines and it tells me I have an unresolved import:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker
```

I have ran

```
>>>import sqlalchemy
>>>sqlalchemy.__version__
```

In the python interpreter and it says I have version 1.3.17 installed so I believe that means that sqlalchemy is installed correctly but VS Code does not see it for some reason.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you create environment?

If no:

**1.Create Environment:**

On your file system, create a project folder for this tutorial, such as hello_flask.

In that folder, use the following command (as appropriate to your computer) to create a virtual environment named env based on your current interpreter:

```
# macOS/Linux
sudo apt-get install python3-venv    # If needed
python3 -m venv env

# Windows
python -m venv env
```

**2.Select**

Open the project folder in VS Code by running code ., or by running VS Code and using the File > Open Folder command.
[image]

**3. Set**

In VS Code, open the Command Palette (View > Command Palette or (Ctrl+Shift+P)). Then select the Python: Select Interpreter command:
[image]

**4.Activate env**

```
source env/bin/activate (Linux/macOS)
```

or

```
env\scripts\activate (Windows)
```

**5.Install Flask**

```
# macOS/Linux
pip3 install flask

# Windows
pip install flask
```

**6. Ensure Pylint is installed within this virtual environment**

```
pip install pylint
```

[Pylint](https://donjayamanne.github.io/pythonVSCodeDocs/docs/troubleshooting_linting/)

**7. Set your python path like this to your env path like this:**

```
{
    "python.pythonPath": "/path/to/your/venv/bin/python",
}
```

[VSCode Workspace](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settings-file-locations)

[flask via VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/tutorial-flask)

Comment: I created an environment and followed your steps and VS Code still says my SQLAlchemy imports are unresolved

Comment: Follow the 6th step

Comment: Please follow step 6 and 7 and be sure if you installed pip install pylint.

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck for 2 days (beginner) with the same problem and tested many ways. I figured out this way:

1. Set your python path like this to your env path like this in VSCODE:

```
{   
  "python.defaultInterpreterPath": "c:/dev/ala/venv/Scripts/python.exe" 
}
```

2. If you are coding in VSCODE (Windows10) I also called from the terminal: python instead of python3 and solved the problem